# Ubuntu won't suspend, shutdown, etc

Tags: usb, 13.10, shutdown, suspend

I've read everything I can find and can't seem to fix this. I removed novatel_3g_suspend for etc/pm/sleep.d (this fixed it initially but only once and issue persisted afterwards), removed toshset, and tried shutting down via the terminal.

When I shut down I get this error:

```
i2400m_usb 1-1.1:1.0: BM-ACK: URB error -71, retrying
```

that just sits there a black screen until I hold the power button and force a shutdown

When I turn it back on I get this:

```
i2400m_usb 1-1.1:1.0: WiMAX interface wmx0 (64:d4:da:65:91:aa) ready
i2400m_usb 1-1.1:1.0: E: __i2400mu_send_barker: maximum errors in URB exceeded; resetting device
i2400m_usb 1-1.1:1.0: warm reset failed (-71); trying USB reset
```

Then I get this line repeating:

```
i2400m_usb 1-1.1:1.0: BM-ACK: URB error -71, retrying
```

After a second or two it disapears and I get the login screen

I have an Asus laptop with a 2nd gen i5, 6gb ram, and Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix:
Basically I added i2400m_usb to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and everything mentioned above is gone